# Not automatically login to Google+ using UIWebView (iOS)?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, google-plus, autologin

- I have a question about authentication with UIWebView.
- I want to login in webview in plus.google.co
- I sign in in google plus one time as shown in
  https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in
- When user go to google+ page again in UIWebView then program should be automatically
  logged in and save the user's session. But in fact it is not keep logged in.How can i keep          user logged in for google+ although user is one time sign in for Google+ in my application.
- I also checked condition for this as :[[GPPSignIn sharedInstance]
  authentication] and it return true that i am logged in already.but when i checked in uiwebview by pushing new ViewController then it ask me to sign in.
- And When i open plus.google.com in safari in iPhone then it show me
  as a login user.

  I searched a lot but can not find an answer.please help me out from
  this.

Comment: Why don't you improve your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15848577/can-i-automatically-login-to-google-using-uiwebview-ios instead of posting a new question?

Comment: ok. i am going to edit this and improve this question.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly you have implemented sign in with the iOS SDK, but you would like to enable sign in for your mobile web browser following these instructions:

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in

These are for a native iOS application.  To implement sign in for mobile web you should follow the instructions for sign in on the web:

https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/

Sorry if this doesn't answer your question directly, but if it doesn't please give more details about your problem.

Comment: thanks for your kind suggestion.But where i put this javascript code in iOS?can you please guide me,i am new to this concept.I am using objective c language.thanks in advance.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't fit with iOS. You can build out your mobile client in Objective C--rendering the button, performing actions, etc. Or you can use JavaScript to build out a WEB client for the corresponding website version of your app. But these instructions are targeted at building cross-platform integrations.

Answer (score 0):

Sign In with Google is now supported through the new [Google Sign In iOS SDK](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios). Migration instructions for users of the Google+ Sign In SDK are available [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/quick-migration-guide).